# Is there a unique solution of $\gamma(t)= f''(t)f(t) $ with $f(0) =0$ and $f'(0)=1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider,
\begin{align*}
\gamma(t) &= f''(t)f(t) \\
f(0) &=0 \quad f'(0)=1
\end{align*}
where $f(t)$ is an unknown function and $\gamma(t)$ is a known function.

Is there a unique solution for $f$?

#### Context

This differential equation came up in work that I am doing in which the function $\gamma$ is very complicated. I was more interested in knowing if there is a unique solution but thought that it would be possible (and simple) to solve explicitly for $f$ as a function(al) of $\gamma$ but after @Winther solution and comments realize that in general it is not simple.

Comment: I doubt this has an elementary analytical solution for general $\gamma$. Maybe for some special cases for $\gamma(t)$. We can for example easily construct solutions by taking any function $g(t)$ with $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)=1$ and then take $\gamma = gg''$. Then $f(t)=g(t)$ is a solution.

Comment: Thanks. In hindsight not a great question... For some reason I thought that it would possible to solve for $f$ as a function of $\gamma$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this has an elementary analytical solution for general $\gamma$, but we can easily construct solutions by taking any function $g(t)$ with $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)=1$ and then take $\gamma = gg''$. By construction we have that $f(t)=g(t)$ is a solution.

One case we can solve is $\gamma(t) = C$ since then

$$f'' f = C \implies f''f' = \frac{Cf'}{f} \implies \frac{f'^2}{2} = C\log(f) + D$$

Now since $f(0)=0$ we only have a solution when $C=0$ for which

$$f(t) = t$$

Comment: Thanks. With a particular choice of $\gamma$ and the initial conditions, does the function $f$ need to be unique?

Comment: @user103828 I think so, but I will have to think more about how to show it. I will try to look more into it when I get some free time.